# Given N points how to find the maximum number of points which are on a circle?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

Yesterday, an interesting question comes to mind, `Given N points, how do you find the maximum number of points that are on a circle?`

Can you suggest anything other than brute-force?  What is O(?)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that there is O(N^3*log N) algorithm :)

```
iterate through all pairs of points - O(N^2)
    for each point of the rest compute radius of circle including that point and the selected pair of points - O(N)
    sort points by this radius - O(N*log N)
    select from the resulting array the biggest group with same radius - O(N)
```

Actually given two points and radius two circles are generally possible, but taking this into account (splitting each group into to) will not change algorithm complexity.

Comment: +1. Also the sorting nicely handles numeric precision problems, since you can set a tolerance and then find the largest number of radii within that tolerance in linear time, by stepping 2 index variables (identifying the current smallest and current largest circles) through the sorted list.

Comment: Instead of radius, you can represent circle going through points P and Q by distance of it's centre from PQ line with positive values on one side and negative values on the other (all possible centres lie on a line that is orthogonal to PQ and intersects it half way between P and Q). That will uniquely map the set of all such circles to real numbers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second line? There are infinitely many circles that go through those 2 points, or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 7):

Except for degenerate cases, any three points on a plane are on a circle. So an obvious O(n<sup>4</sup>) algorithm is to enumerate all sets of three points that are not on a line (O(n<sup>3</sup>)), calculate the center of the circle (maybe there can be two, I'm not sure) going through the three points, and then iterate through the other points and check which ones are on the same circle, count, and after algorithm has finished, report the maximum.

Comment: I also solve it like that but I think that it is nothing than brute-force

Comment: Yes it is brute-force, but I wonder if there is really any asymptotically faster algorithm available. The last O(n) (search for more points on the same circle) can be improved in practice maybe by having some kind of spatial indexing in use, so that you can more efficiently find points near the proposed circumference, but still in worst case it would be O(n).

Comment: Consider: any circle produced by a triplet that overlaps with other points will be produced again by another triplet, since you are iterating through all of them.  You can simply tally the number of times a particular circle is hit, making this an O(n^3) algorithm.

Comment: Store the centre and radius for each triplet, and then go through this lsit to find the multiples on any given centre and radius.

Comment: @bdares: That's right, but don't forget to "scale back" that count.  If the circle is hit n times, then we must have that n = (k choose 3) for some k, since any 3 of the k points will produce the same circle. k is the final answer that we want, not n.

Comment: Um.. right.  I hate this math stuff, I thought computers are supposed to do the hard stuff for us...

Comment: @antti.huima: Good solution (you just have to add treatment for special border in case that the 3 points are collinear)

Comment: @bdares: no, computers are supposed to do the repetitive stuff.